# What's the best way to write math expressions in plain text, for example in the context of an online class?

Tags: notation

I find it hard to write down math expressions during my online classes, the website our teacher uses  doesn't support LaTeX or anything similar. I have already suggested this feature to the developers of the website, but in the meantime, I would like to know if there exists any guidelines/norms, or any software that could be used to help me write expressions in plain text, in the form of keyboard shortcuts or by using an interface.

It would be something in the form of:

`Alt + P` -> `π`
`^5` -> `⁵`

### Even better would be:
`x = (-b \pm \sqrt(b^2 - 4ac))/2a`

```
    -b ± √(b²-4ac)
x = ——————————————
         2a
```

I believe it would make our classes much easier to read and comprehend.

Comment: 1. Why do you have to use the website you teacher uses? 2. Why not writing them in online class on paper and convert them after that to latex?

Comment: 1. Our teacher is required by the school to use this specific website. 2. I write down my classes on paper, but I have to use the app's chat to communicate with our teacher, ask and respond to questions.

Comment: You might find ideas by looking through old sci.math posts (before 2000 is best), since everything there was ASCII only. Also, I recommend avoiding the annoying and unnecessary backslashes, and also avoid LaTeX code when the meaning wouldn't be apparent to someone unfamiliar with LaTeX (pm not good; sqrt is fine; pi is fine; cup is not good; union is good). For example, with the quadratic formula, write x  = [-b +/- sqrt(b^2 - 4ac)]/(2a). Note the use of both [...] and (...) for reading clarity. Use words instead of trying to symbolize everything: complement(A union B) = (A intersect B).

Comment: I had 6 characters left in the previous comment, so I can't fix it there, but of course two more complement's are needed. However, in the case of a lot of set algebra, if you're dealing with more than a mostly one-shot statement of something like a De Morgan identity, you'd probably want to define some abbreviations, and probably use "cup" and "cap" simply so students don't have to unlearn something if they continue in math, and maybe something like c-A for the complement of A, so the previous identity becomes c-(A cup B) = (c-A cap c-B).

Comment: Write questions and solutions on paper. Download Office Lens (or similar) to your phone and photograph your paper. It allows you to save several pictures as a single pdf. Attach to your chat message.

Comment: Would the mathematics environments of a PDF made in LaTeX be illegible if uploaded to the school website?

Comment: If the issue is only to chat, then both sides could work in lyx or some similar latex interpreter, and just copy paste the latex from the app to lyx and back.